# Is Pyramid framework good for embedded cpu ( ARM9 - 64 MB RAM )?

Tags: pylons, pyramid

Is Pyramid framework good for embedded cpu ( ARM9 - 64 MB RAM, linux and lighttpd ) or I need CherryPy ? I looked at CherryPy but it didn't get positive impression .

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for small implementations, you might get better results with Bottle or Flask. Both are minimalistic frameworks in python.